# How to convert a object array into string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The array is this:

```
[{name:'name1',id:'id1',val:'001},
 ...
 {name:'name10',id:'id10',val:'010}]
```

We want to store in the database as a long text string:

```
name1,id1,001;...;name10,id10,010
```

values separated by semicolon and comma.

Is there any convenient `join` or something else to achieve it? (I guess there must be something better than `for` loop.)

Comment: If you are happy with Jquery then this one is easy: http://jsfiddle.net/XWCv8/413/ And since the question is not tagged with Jquery I cant add it as answer :(

Comment: Since that's not an array, but an object, you cannot use `join`, and won't get deterministic order unless you are explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```javascript
function joinValues(arr, j1, j2) {
  return arr.map(function(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
      return o[k];
    }).join(j1)
  }).join(j2);
}

var obj = [{a:1,b:2},{a:'x',b:'y'}];
joinValues(obj, ',', ';'); // => "1,2;x,y"
```

Comment: Awesome! That is certainly beautiful JavaScript. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
array.map(function(o){
  var values = Object.keys(o).map(function(key){
    return o[key];
  });
  return values.join(',');
}).reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + ';' + b;
});
```

Beware there might be compat issues depending on your platform (`map`, `reduce`, `Object.keys` not available everywhere yet!)

Also, take into account that properties order in regular objects is [not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). With this approach, theoretically you could end up having `name1,id1,001;...;id10,name10,010`. That might be an issue when mapping the string back to objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't a built-in language feature for that, but if you can use ES6, it can look quite elegant

```
Object.values = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

// so to convert your data
data.map(o => Object.values(o).join(',')).join(';');
```